# unknown error: unable to discover open pages Chrome Driver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using the Selenium GEB for the Automation Testing using Groovy.

My Chrome Version updated to the Version 110.0.5481.78 (Official Build) (64-bit). So I Downloaded the latest Chrome Driver Version from official website. https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

I have downloaded the version that Supports the Version 110.X.XXXX Now Once I Updated My chrome Driver started Crashing And I Could not find the Proper Solution to It so Finally I am posting Question.

Error

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System
```

Your Response I highly appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: I could see the Processes in the Task manager though. I can Kill and try that again but I did restart my System once. that suppose to kill the process?

Comment: Just to keep the Answer more clear -> Go to Task manager -> Check for any ChromeDriver.exe if Running. -> Kill every Chrome Driver and Run Script Again.